# Mongo Oplog format in 5.0.2 contains 's' prefix on updates

Tags: mongodb

I've noticed a difference in the Oplog between v4.4.6 and v5.0.2 when performing updates.

When updating a field in the document, it seems to add the character 's' as a prefix.
For example when **myField** (**which is an array**) is updated:

```
{ "$v" : 2, "diff" : { "smyField" : ....
```

On version 4.4.6 it was:

```
{ "$v" : 1, "$set" : { "myField.2" : ....
```

Does anyone know whether this is a bug in 5.0.2 or intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal oplog structure is undocumented and subject to change between minor versions and patch releases.

Use [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams) for watching the oplog.  They were introduced to provide consistency between versions.

If that naming change doesn't break replication, that would mean the secondary nodes are expecting it, so it was most likely intentional.

Comment: That's interesting, since projects like RedHat Debezium look at the Oplog directly.

Comment: Perhaps that's why Debezium doesn't list MongoDB 5.0 support yet.

Comment: Just seen there is a open ticket in Debezium's backlog to potentially support change streams in the future.